# Cannot import class using karma-webpack and babel. The imported class is undefined

Tags: javascript, karma-runner, ecmascript-6, webpack, babeljs

I'm using karma-webpack and babel in a project to write ES6 tests with executed with Jasmine and import ES6 classes used by my unit tests.

I noticed that I wasn't able to export a class written in ES6 to use it in my unit tests. Here is my code:

Hello.js

```
export default class Hello {
  constructor() {
    this.a = 'b';
  }
}
```

Hello.test.js

```
"use strict";

import Hello from './hello';

describe(" hello unit tests", function () {
  console.log('Hello: ' + JSON.stringify(Hello));
});
```

When I run `karma start`, the `console.log` displays:
`PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Mac OS X 0.0.0) LOG LOG: 'Hello: undefined'`

But I noticed that if I replace the code in the `Hello.js` file by:

```
const Hello = {'a': 'b'};

export default Hello;
```

It works when I run `karma start`:
`PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Mac OS X 0.0.0) LOG LOG: 'Hello: {"a":"b"}'`

Here is my `karma.conf.js`

```
var webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ["jasmine"],
    files: [
        "./tests/**/*.test.js"
    ],
    preprocessors: {
        "./tests/**/*.js": ["webpack",  "sourcemap"]
    },
    webpack: {
        module: {
            loaders: [{
              test: /\.js/,
              exclude: /(node_modules)/,
              loader: 'babel-loader'
            }]
        },
        devtool: "inline-source-map",
    },
    webpackMiddleware: {
        progress: false,
        stats: false,
        debug: true,
        noInfo: true,
        silent: true 
    },
    plugins: [
        require("karma-webpack"),
        require("karma-jasmine"),
        require("karma-phantomjs-launcher"),
        require("karma-sourcemap-loader"),
        require("karma-spec-reporter"),
    ],
    specReporter: {maxLogLines: 5},
    reporters: ["spec"],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ["PhantomJS"],
    singleRun: true
  });
};
```

My project structure:

```
karma.conf.js
tests/
  Hello.js
  Hello.test.js
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: I wonder what output you would have expected?

Comment: I would expect a more explicit behaviour. E.g. just a string "Function" or "Class" just to know that the class has been well defined. I don't know if such a behaviour is doable though.

Comment: `JSON.stringify` accepts a second argument, a function, which is used to serialize each value inside the data structure. You could use that to implement such functionality. However, it would not be good if if what you describe was the default behavior. The receiving side of the JSON wouldn't be able to know whether the data literally contained the string `"Function"` or if that was some native function. I.e. there would be no 1:1 mapping between the real data and its JSON representation.

Comment: Yes, it makes sense. I shouldn't use `JSON.stringify()` in this case. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [ECMAScript specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-json.stringify) of `JSON.stringify`:

> Values that do not have a JSON representation (such as undefined and
>   functions) do not produce a String. Instead they produce the undefined
>   value.

Since classes are just syntactic sugar over functions, calling `JSON.stringify(class Foo {})` will yield `undefined`.

Try doing `console.log(Hello)` or `console.log(Hello.name)`, which should yield, respectively, `[Function: Hello]` and `Hello`.

Comment: Good catch! I didn't know this behavior with `JSON.stringify`. Thanks a lot, you saved my day.